# Realizar acciones de suma y multiplicación en carrito de compras luego de evento keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

Saludos comunidad. Estoy intentando que al escribir en un campo de texto la cantidad de un producto, me multiplique dicha cantidad con el precio del producto y me muestre automáticamente el subtotal y que eso se sume al total de la compra.
Es un carrito de compras y en el quiero poder cambiar la cantidad del producto y que el subtotal y total me aparezcan dinamicamente sin necesidad de recargar. Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando:

Este es mi carrito:

```
 <?php
    $total=0;
    if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
    $datos=$_SESSION['carrito'];
?>
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Prod</th>
        <th>Prec.</th>
        <th>Cant.</th>
        <th>Tot(iva)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
 <?php 
    for($i=0;$i<count($datos);$i++){   
    ?>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <?php echo $datos[$i]['Nombre'];?>
      </td>
      <td>
     <b class="precio"><?php echo number_format($datos[$i]['Precio'],2);</b>
     </td>
     <td>
     <input type="number" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Cantidad'];>" 
     class="cantidad">
    </td>
    <?php 
     $subtotal = $datos[$i]['Cantidad']*$datos[$i]['Precio'];
     $subtotal_iva = ($subtotal*$datos[$i]['Iva'])+$subtotal;
     ?>
     <td>
      <b class="subtotal"><?php echo number_format($subtotal_iva,2);?></b>
     </td>
   </tr>

   <?php
       $total_iva = $total + $subtotal_iva; 
       $total= $total+$subtotal_iva;  
      ?>
    </tbody>
<?php
     }
    ?>
    <tr>
     <th colspan="4">
      <b style="float: right;">Total(IVA inc.):<?php echo $total_iva;?></b>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">
        <b class="total">Total a pagar:<?php echo $total;?></b>
      </th>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Y esto es lo que tengo hecho con js

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cantidad").keyup(function(){
     var acumulado = parseInt(0);
     var cantidad = $(".cantidad").val();
     var monto = $(".precio").val();

     acumulado = acumulado+(monto*cantidad);
     $(".subtotal").html(acumulado);
     //$(".total").html(acumulado);
     });
    });
   </script>
```

Hasta ahora no he tenido éxito con eso. Lo que quiero hacer es que al escribir en el input de cantidad multiplique el precio del producto por la cantidad escrita, me de un subtotal y a su vez ese subtotal se sume al monto total del carrito y que me aparezca dinamicamente, como he dicho he intentado pero no he podido. No conozco mucho de js

Comment: Buscaste sobre .innertHTML?

Comment: He buscado varias cosas ya Andy, pero no logro hacerlo bien. Lo mas que pude fue que me calculara el subtotal y lo mostrara pero nada mas lo hace de un producto de la lista del carrito, con los demas no lo hace

Comment: Podrias aislar el problema a solo javascript y jquery como tienes en los tags, es decir, eliminar el codigo php ?